# Jquery Regex Match for number with comma

Tags: jquery, regex

I have price like "1,200" and I want to fetch this as 1200 but in my case after comma it is showing nothing. How to resolve this.

Below is Jquery Code,

```
total_price = 0;
      $('.count_total').each(function(){
        var get_price = $(this).text().match(/^\d+,\d+$/);
        total_price += get_price;
        var total = commaSeparateNumber(total_price);
        $(".total_price").text(currency+"."+total_price);
      });
```

Comment: maybe something like this `^\d+(,\d+)*$`

Comment: It will return if 1,200 is there means 1 only will come after it is not taking.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersenn It is showing "0".

Comment: $(this).text().replace(/^\d+,\d+$/, '');  and this¿

Comment: +$(this).text().replace(',', '')

Comment: @gaetanoM  I have used your code and its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = "1,200"
price = parseInt(p.split(',').join(''))
```

Comment: That's JavaScript and JQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: @Ishtiaque05 Actually In my case I have price like Rs.2,300  To fetch this I have done like below 'var get_price = Number($(this).text().match(/\d+/)[0]);' but after "Comma" it is taking I meant 300 is not coming it fetching only 2. How to fetch this is what I want.

Comment: I got Solution thanks for everyone for support.   Below is working code 'var price = $(this).text().replace(',', '');
        var get_price = Number(price.match(/\d+/)[0]);'

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to replace , and trim for trailing space.

```js
var get_price = "1,200";
var result = get_price.replace(/[,]+/g, "").trim();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` and can replace all comma with blank or you can use `split` and `join`:

```js
p = "1,200"
price = parseInt(p.split(',').join(''));
console.log(price);

p = "1,200";
console.log(parseInt(p.replace(/[,]/g,'')));
```